# how to find the text of an element in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello I have html markup like this:

```
<div class="expandNode expand">
<input id="100" type="checkbox" value="100" data-parent="">
<span>Office/Commercial</span>
</div>
```

In the console when I do `$('#100')` I get this:

```
[<input id=​"100" type=​"checkbox" value=​"100" data-parent>​]
```

What I need is the text within the span i.e. Office/Commercial.

How can I do this?

Comment: The HTML isn't valid. you need to close the `input` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('#100').next('span').text();
```

Or like:

```
$('.expandNode span').text();   // not suggested
```

Theremore the input tag needs to be closed and still I don't suggest to use numbers for ID elements ( < HTML5 )

**A more flexible and future-proof way to achieve the same would be:**

```
$('#100').closest('.expandNode').find('span').text();
```

Additionally, if you're sure there'll be only ONE `<span>` inside the parent element you can go for:

```
$('#100').siblings('span').text();
```

That way you don't have to rely on `span` be the immediate `.next()` element.

Comment: +1, For the second way, the first I believe is awful(relying on the `next` selector, maintenance problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#100").next('span').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your span to give it an ID or class (OPTIONAL):

```
<span class="expand-span">Office/Commercial</span>
```

Then use this jQuery code to find it:

```
$('.expandNode').children('.expand-span');
```

If you don't want to give your span a class or ID, you can use:

```
$('.expandNode').children('span');
```